# Probability distributions on a unit circle in the function space $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Suppose there is an interval $I=[0,1]$, and you throw $N$ balls into $I$ independently following a continuous distribution $f(x)$ on $I$. When $N$ is very large, the **density distribution** of $N$ balls on $I$ will follow another distribution $g(x)$, which, after scaling by $N$, will approximate $f(x)$:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1\left|\frac{g(x)}{N}-f(x)\right|\text{d}x=0
$$

Now if $N$ is still large but also **finite**, can we have some approximation as to what extent $\cfrac{g(x)}{N}$ is deviated from $f(x)$?

I was thinking about defining a probability distribution on the unit circle $B_1$ of $L^1$:$\{h(x)|\int_0^1|h(x)|dx=1\}$, clearly $g(x)/N$ and $f(x)$ both belong to $B_1$, but I don't know how to proceed to calculate the distribution.

Comment: Do you know about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz_inequality?

Comment: @Stockfish. Nope, but thanks for it, looks very relevant!